# Can a query infer a subClassOf?

Tags: database, sparql, rdf, rdfs, turtle-rdf

I have a set of information (not all shown, of course):

```
s:Marshmallow    rdfs:subClassOf    s:Android
```

```
s:galaxyEdge6    s:OS       s:Marshmallow;
                 s:price    350.
...
```

I want to query phones that are both Android and have a price less than 400.

My query:

```
SELECT ?phone WHERE {
?phone     s:OS               ?system
?system    rdfs:subClassOf    s:Android
?phone     s:price            ?value
} FILTER (?value < 400)
```

Based on my query above, do I need to include `?system   rdfs:subClassOf    s:Android`? Or can I remove that line and change the one above it to: `?phone    s:OS    s:Android`?

Comment: try it, what happens if you do it? Spoiler: it should be empty because in your data the graph pattern is `?phone     s:OS               ?system .
?system    rdfs:subClassOf    s:Android`, i.e. 2 edges from the phone to Android as OS

Comment: Also, you should be aware of the fact that you're using the same URI as class and as individual.

Comment: Hm? I am not quite sure what you mean :/

Comment: Mean by what? in your data the phone is connect to an operating system which is connected to Android. So you SPARQL query has to use exactly this graph pattern. Just doing `?phone    s:OS    s:Android` doesn't match anything in your data. And there is no inferencing possible. A common inference rule would be `X rdf:type C . C rdfs:subClassOf D => X rdf:type D` - this is clearly not covered by your data.

Comment: By the way, your question contains some errors/types: `s:Marshmaloow` and `s:Anroid` as well as the filter being outside of the query. Please make your examples as correct as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
s:Marshmallow    rdfs:subClassOf    s:Android
```

This entails that any individual that is `a s:Marshmallow` is also `a s:Android`. You don't use `a` (`rdf:type`) as a predicate, so there is nothing to infer.

To illustrate why it should even be dangerous to infer such a thing, consider `foaf:membershipClass`. This links an individual (`foaf:Group`) to a class of its members in such a way that both are equivalent (i.e. being a member of the group infers having a specific class, and vice-versa). Yet it would be dangerous to infer from `foaf:membershipClass ex:MyClass` something like `foaf:membershipClass owl:Thing`, when `owl:Thing` is obviously a superclass here.

You have two options of dealing with this. Without modifying the ontology, you can simply turn `s:OS` into `a`, then you can infer `s:galaxyEdge6 a s:Android` from `s:galaxyEdge6 a s:Marshmallow`. However, I don't like this approach, since it's too far from a real-world "is a" relationship, and it's harder to query the OS.

Personally I would choose SKOS for modelling the concept of an OS, i.e. having `s:Android a skos:Concept` and `s:Marshmallow skos:broader s:Android`. However, you will most likely also need OWL to specify that having `s:OS <narrower>` entails `s:OS <broader>` (which you would have to do without using SKOS anyway).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it was really helpful & insightful for someone who is getting up to speed with semantics & ontologies